# How can I force the mouse cursor to stay in the window of another game, when XCOM / XCOM 2 is running in the background?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-2

**The scenario is as follows**:

I run *XCOM* or *XCOM 2* (the problem occurs for both). I do a task change to Windows and start another game (i.e. leave *XCOM* running in the background), say *Heroes of the Storm* (*HotS*). Whenever I have an extended waiting period in the other game, I'd switch back to *XCOM* and continue there.

This worked perfectly for some games (e.g. *Battle Worlds: Kronos*) but when running *XCOM* this has some severe disadvantages. I'm playing on my main screen (right side) and have another secondary screen set up on the left side - just showing windows desktop.

**The problem**:

The mouse cursor doesn't stay in the *HotS* window. So whenever I hit the left side of my main screen and accidentally click, I'll switch to Windows. The mouse cursor isn't bound to the game's screen.

As said: this problem occurs specifically for *XCOM* / *XCOM 2* and is not universal (although I can't say for sure it **only** happens for *XCOM*). Does anyone have a solution for this behavior? I want to keep running *XCOM* in the background while playing *HotS* and still keep focus only in *HotS*.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to have a solution, but I also don't really understand the problem you're describing. You click outside of the game and it switches to what you clicked on? That seems correct. What did you want to happen instead?

Comment: The mouse should remain inside of HotS window and not just leave game window. Mouse should be bound to the game (which is normal behavior). I'll try to clarify my question in that regards.

Comment: It isn't something that the background gaming is doing; it's something that the foreground game is _not_ doing - capturing the mouse in exclusive mode. Not all games capture the mouse, and there's rarely anything you can do about it.

Comment: If I end XCOM it works perfectly. So this problem only occurs in combination of XCOM running in Background and other game (e.g. HotS in foreground).

Comment: I don't have a way to test it, but in my XCOM2 under options>video settings there is an option to lock the mouse to the window. Not quite what you're asking but it may have the desired effect of preventing the mouse from being detected by XCOM2 while in the other game.

Comment: Can you recreate the effect with other titles? Either something else with HOTS or XCOM and something else?

Comment: @JackArbiter That part I already tried. I'm even pretty sure that is the underlying reason of the observed behavior. Nonetheless no matter what I select there, it affects behavior of HotS.

Comment: @T.J.L. HOTS with Battelworld: Kronos doesn't show this affect, same for others. First one I found was XCOM and XCOM 2 - not others yet. That's why I've written the question around XCOM, as all indications show XCOM as origin of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than addressing the issue with XCOM directly, I suggest an indirect solution using window management software.

I have been using [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) to manage my windows and mouse cursor for many years, and although I haven't used it myself, there is a feature that lets you lock your cursor to the current monitor or active window by pressing a hotkey. See the screenshot below:

[image: DisplayFusion functions tab]

DisplayFusion has a basic free mode, but also has a 30 day trial for Pro, so you can test both of these functions and see if it works before buying. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've given up hope - this could really work. Thanks.